# Count instances of a pattern's match in a real-time log file, in a specific time frame, using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, monitoring, tail, pattern-matching

I've to intercept a pattern in a log file and, when this pattern is matched for 5 times in 5 minutes, send an alert...

I've wrote this lines, but I'm stuck... I don't know how to handle the time frame...

Can you help me please?

Roberto.

```
$count = get-content test.txt -Tail 1 -Wait | select-string -pattern "auth" -simplematch
$count.length
```

I've tried other approach, but nothing to do...

```
$file = "test.txt"
$mymatch = "auth"
#$FirstEventTime = Get-Date
#$LastEventTime = Get-Date
$Err = 0
$Range =@(1,2,3,4)
$Tailfile = Get-Content $file -Tail 1 -Wait | select-string -pattern $mymatch -simplematch | foreach ($mymatch) {
    if($Err -lt 1){
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier StartEvent -Sender windows.timer
        $Err++
        }
    #elseif ($Err -eq [1-4])
    elseif ($Range -contains $Err){
        $Err++ }
    else {
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier LastEvent -Sender windows.timer
        $FisrtEvent = (get-event StartEvent).TimeGenerated
        $LastEvent = (get-event LastEvent).TimeGenerated
        $Elapsed = $LastEvent-$FisrtEvent
        $realElasped = ($elapsed).TotalMinutes
        [math]::Round($realElasped)

            if ($realElasped -lt 5) {
                echo "sendmail......"
                $Err = 0}
            else {
            $Err = 0
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of occurrences in an interval is a useful alert condition, but it is a non-trivial program to write. Most simple tail implementations don't have such a feature.

Consider implementing a log aggregation system that has extensible alert conditions. For example, [Graylog has X messages in Y minutes](https://docs.graylog.org/en/stable/pages/streams/alerts.html#message-count-condition). Yes, it is a much bigger project than tailing one log. However it can ingest event log and syslog as well, and do similar things for any event from any host.

Comment: You're absolutely right John! We've Kafka and other Apache friends in the serverfarm! Unfortunately I've some servers in a segregated network that cannot reaches hosts in severfarm subnets...

Answer (score 0):

Just for who has the same need, I've fixed my script and now it works!

```
$MailArgs = @{
    From = bla, bla, bla....
}

$file = "Test.txt"
$FolderLogs = "E:\TMP"
$mymatch1 = "autentica"
$mymatch2 = "WS ERROR"
$Err = 0
$Range =@(1,2,3,4)
$Tailfile = Get-Content $file -Tail 1 -Wait | ?{ $_ -match $mymatch1 -and $_ -match $mymatch2 } | ForEach-Object {
    if($Err -lt 1){
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier StartEvent -Sender windows.timer
        $Err++
    }
    elseif ($Range -contains $Err) {
        $Err++ 
    }
    else {
        New-Event -SourceIdentifier LastEvent -Sender windows.timer
        $FisrtEvent = (get-event StartEvent).TimeGenerated
        $LastEvent = (get-event LastEvent).TimeGenerated
        $Elapsed = $LastEvent-$FisrtEvent
        $realElasped = ($elapsed).TotalMinutes
        [math]::Round($realElasped)

        if ($realElasped -lt 5) {
            Send-MailMessage @MailArgs 2>&1 > $FolderLogs\MailLogs.txt
            $Err = 0
        }
        else {
            $Err = 0
        }
    }
}
```